# How to store and retrieve data in Isolated Storage File?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an requirement of store and retrieve data from isolated storage file.I will store data in the file from Winforms application but I need to retrieve that data from file in ASP.NET application.I have successfully saved the data in Isolated file through winforms application here is the code

```
            IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain();

            string[] fileNames = isoStore.GetFileNames(fileName);

            if (fileNames != null && fileNames.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in fileNames)
                {
                    if (file == fileName)
                    {
                        isSuccess = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        isSuccess = false;
                }
            }

            if (!isSuccess)
            {                 
                oStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, isoStore);
                writer = new StreamWriter(oStream);
                writer.WriteLine(licenseCode);
                writer.Close();
            }
```

In ASP.NET application I will retrieve data from the isolated storage file.The code is shown below
                IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain();

```
            string[] fileNames = isoStore.GetFileNames(fileName);                 

            //Retrieve License Code from Isolated storage
            iStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, isoStore);

            reader = new StreamReader(iStream);
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                output = line;
            }
            return output;
```

But I am unable to retrieve the data which is stored in Isolated storage file from ASP.NET application (string[] fileNames = isoStore.GetFileNames(fileName); this string[] returns 0) which indicates no file exists in the machine.

Could anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isolated storage is isolated (as the name says already). So you wont be able to access isolated storage from different assemblys. I assume your ASP.NET app is not in the same assembly as your Winform app

Comment: Yes you are right both are different projects,then how could I retrieve data from Isolated storage file in ASP.NET application ?

Comment: @Ramalingam: as fix_likes_coding already stated, isolatedstorage is isolated, and therefore you can not access it from different applications.