# UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using `FtpWebRequest` to download my file from ftp. However, when the app goes to the line `FileStream` which I declare to write the file out.

Below is my Download function:

```
public void Download(List <string> path)
        {
            try
            {
                string timenow = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Today.Day.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Today.Hour.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Today.Minute.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Today.Second.ToString();
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\StudySystemFile\" + timenow);
                if (!dir.Exists)
                    dir.Create();

                foreach (string p in path)
                {
                    FtpWebRequest request;
                    request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftp.Hostname + p));
                    request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ftp.FtpAccount, ftp.FtpPassword);
                    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                    request.KeepAlive = false;
                    request.UseBinary = true;
                    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                    Stream reader = response.GetResponseStream();
                    FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\StudySystemFile\" + timenow, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        file.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    }

                    reader.Close();
                    file.Close();
                    response.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(p);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ask the user where he or she wants to save the file OR save to a location such as application data OR enforce that the application has elevated privileges (but still, Anti-Virus might block access).

Answer (score 1):

Your application doesn't have permission to write to that directory. You can force the UAC prompt by right-clicking on your project and adding a new `Application Manifest File`. In this file, replace

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

with

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

A better idea would be to write to a directory that doesn't require admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

The user running the program does not have permission to create the file at `C:\StudySystemFile\` check that the folder exists and whatever user the program is running as can create files there without a UAC prompt.

Likely what is happening is when you create the folder with `Create()` it is inheriting permissions from `C:\` which does not have write permissions for files, you only get folder creation permissions.

You either need to create the folder outside the program or when you call `Create()` you need to [set the permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6esbt79.aspx).

Comment: Hi, @Scott Thanks for your reply, and I found my directory created by `DirectoryInfo` is `read-only`

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting `UnauthorizedAccessException` .The exception that is thrown when the operating system denies access because of an I/O error or a specific type of security error.

It is clearly a **permission issue**.

In case of Vista/Windows 7/8, `C:\` drive is considered as system drive, and need administrator privileges for your process in order to create files directly under it.

Try running your process with administrator or `Run Visual Studio as Administrator`, and it should work.

Comment: It would be better to just create the folder correctly with proper permissions instead of running as an administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I thought as same as Scott.

Comment: @CYB You are already creating the file with `ReadWrite Access` in your code, so the thing is that your user, that is running VS doesn't have administrator privileges. So, that is the only option.

Comment: @BhushanFirake I try this way, but it still throws the exception.

Comment: @CYB if u r using windows7 or 8, see my answer else u will need to change drive for folder.

Comment: @BhushanFirake Yes, my OS is win7; however, I tried to write to my other disks. It still threw the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Framework are you using?  What installation/launch method are you using? (ie, clickonce)  And like the other poster suggested, have you checked the permissions on that folder on your C: drive?  Right click the folder and check the security tab, make sure the logged in user has modify as well as read access to the folder.

If you only need the file on a temporary basis, then look into writing to IsolatedStorage.
[How to store and retrieve data in Isolated Storage File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416091/how-to-store-and-retrieve-data-in-isolated-storage-file)